# Distinct number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm working on the following question while studying for my qual. in Algebra:  Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups. Show that if $P$ and $Q$ are distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, then their intersection is a normal subgroup of $G$

There was a hint to show that $|P : P \cap Q| = p$, which I've established, but I'm unsure of how this helps.  Do anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

An index $p$ subgroup of a finite $p$-group is always normal, so $P\cap Q$ is normal in $P$,  and in $Q$....

Comment: Fixed under conjugation. Thank you!